# To add increment value in ID class

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm new in `javascript`. How to add the ID value in the `span HTML` inner HTML file.

My Html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>Special characters are:<br/>
<span class="We2" datas2="display">Sample Datas are...</span><br/>
<div><span datas2="display">How do I increment the id or class when I dynamically add the content...</span></div>

<div><span datas2="display">when the code actually runs, 10 will get spit out to</span></div>

<span datas2class="We2" datas2="display">How do I increment the id or class when I dynamically add the content...</span>

<span datas2class="We2" datas2="display">$$
```

How do I increment the id or class when I dynamically add the content...

```
<span datas2class="We2" datas2="display">How do I increment the id or class when I dynamically add the content...</span>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm expecting output is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>Special characters are:<br/>
<span id="value1" class="We2" datas2="display">Sample Datas are...</span><br/>
<div><span id="value2" datas2="display">How do I increment the id or class when I dynamically add the content...</span></div>

<div><span id="value3" datas2="display">when the code actually runs, 10 will get spit out to</span></div>

<span id="value4" datas2class="We2" datas2="display">How do I increment the id or class when I dynamically add the content...</span>

<span id="value5" datas2class="We2" datas2="display">$$
```

How do I increment the id or class when I dynamically add the content...

```
<span id="value6" datas2class="We2" datas2="display">How do I increment the id or class when I dynamically add the content...</span>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dynamically insert element with id isn't a good practice. Add a custom property instead like: data-id

Comment: `ID`s should be unique and should justify the purpose of element. That's a good convention. So you should manually enter IDs. And if you cannot, please explain your usecase and we can suggest you alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow some steps for that:

1. You need to get all the elements with attribute `datas2 = "display"` which can be done using `querySelectorAll('[datas2 = "display"]')`
2. You need to declare a global variable, `j`, that will change the count of the `id` value which is concatenated with `value` like `value+i`

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('[datas2 = "display"]');
var j = 1;
for(var i=0; i< elem.length; i++){
  //set id value
  elem[i].id = 'value'+j;
  j++;
}
```

```html
<div>Special characters are:<br/>
<span class="We2" datas2="display">Sample Datas are...</span><br/>
<div><span datas2="display">How do I increment the id or class when I dynamically add the content...</span></div>

<div><span datas2="display">when the code actually runs, 10 will get spit out to</span></div>

<span datas2class="We2" datas2="display">How do I increment the id or class when I dynamically add the content...</span>

<span datas2class="We2" datas2="display">$$
```

You will require to use browser `inspect element` on that `<span>` elements in below snippet to check the `id` is present correctly.

Comment: @user49758 glad to help :)

Comment: I would like to add `id` value in all the `<span` HTML tag after `DOM` is loaded. The `class` is no need to find. How to achieve this?

Comment: @user49758 in that case use `var elem = document.querySelectorAll('span);`

Comment: Simple and beautiful solutions. I would like to escape some particular HTML with specific `class` tag `e.g. <span class="enum1"`. It's means no need ID value in `<span class="enum1"`. It's possible?